# Workflow for developing in Android Studios and Unity in parallel

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing an application that has a portion written in Unity and a portion in Java with Android Studios (a game with native UI and menus).

The default Unity workflow is to override the Android project when I make changes on the Unity side and export, which is cumbersome when my team is trying to develop both ends in parallel.

What is the suggested workflow in this case? Ideally I'd be able to link to the Android project generated by Unity from an independent Android Studios project that is not altered during Unity exports.

Suggestions for the ideal workflow to cover this use case for Xcode and Unity is also appreciated, although the append option during export seems to be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

> The default Unity workflow is to override the Android project when I make changes on the Unity side and export, which is cumbersome when my team is trying to develop both ends in parallel.

This **might** be incorrect. You can certainly do that that way, but it is not commonly used, nor ideal way, I suppose.

According to my experience, you should resort to [plugins](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html).

The typical workflow:

- To develop **most** of the apps/games in Unity3D, otherwise, it makes no sense to use U3D, and directly develop in java native shall do.
- For those missing features which are hard to implement in Unity3D, but Android does ship an off-the-shelf component, e.g. VideoPlayer, develop a Unity Android plugin, typically a *.jar file with corresponding AndroidManifest.xml etc. (This is a long story, though)
- Create a folder in U3D, Assets\Plugins\Android, e.g.
- Put the jar and xml to that folder
- In C#, call the functionalities exposed in the jar, see this [doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaClass.html) for details.

Example code:

```
AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"); 
var currentActivity = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity");
currentActivity.Call ("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable (action));
...
var someObject = new AndroidJavaObject (FullClassName);
someObject.Call("SetRect", x, y, width, height); // java class/methods
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, David. We're working with a peculiar use case in that we're trying to develop all the UI/menus/etc. in native Android UI and UIKit for Android and iOS respectively. This is a requirement because a big portion of our game is messaging and we want the best experience possible. 

Most of the "game" portion will be developed in Unity, but the master views/controllers/activities should still be native. An example of this is Fates Forever on iOS.